# SyntaxError: Invalid syntax on Ubuntu Python 3 Terminal

Tags: python, syntax-error

## I'm a novice at coding, just come back to it after being in the dark for so long, currently trying to complete an assignment, advice appreciated! Line 13 syntax error

```
import os
#Imports operating system modules
user_file_search = raw_input('Type Millienium2000 ')
#Prompt the user to enter password
encoded = user_file_search.encode('hex')
#Decodes files based on hex

for root, dirs, files in os.walk ('/Desktop/POP/PoP_Coursework_Assignment/Svr1/documents$'):
    for data in files :
        pass_file = open(os.path.join(root,data)).read()

if(encoded in pass_file):
    print'This could be the pass : {}'.format(os.path.join(root,data))
    print 'Located data: {}'.format(pass_file)
#Prints Data retrieved
```

I've been told that originally it was a indent problem via terminal, I spent some time correcting it I believe and I am now met with

```
File "oswalk.py", line 13
print'This could be the pass : {}'.format(os.path.join(root,data))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax      ^
```

Pointing towards  # {}'
Coding on Ubuntu Python 3
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You say you're on python 3: print needs parentheses

Comment: You are using `Python3` and `print` is a function now, it needs `()` around its arguments.

Comment: Ahh Brilliant, Thanks for the rapid response! Great community, I hope to give back one day when I am more literate in Cyber Security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Python 3+, `print` is not a keyword but a function now, it needs brackets when called:

```
    print ('This could be the pass : {}'.format(os.path.join(root,data)))
    print ('Located data: {}'.format(pass_file))
```

Comment: you mean parenthesis :D gg wp

Comment: Yes parentheses or round brackets =)